# How to set conditional visibility in android

Tags: android, webview, visibility

I want to set visibility of a imageview on the basis of a condition. how would i do it ??

here is my code :

`if (web.canGoBack() != true) {
            bc.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else {
            bc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }`

here bc is the `imageview` over a `webview` which is in `framelayout`

Comment: what exactly your problem is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is fine.

But, if want it in 1 line then.

```
bc.setVisibility(web.canGoBack()? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `bc.setVisibility(View.GONE);`
But the real issue may be your response from `web.canGoBack()`. Please do check that condition is working fine.